# creating sheets in a workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a worksheet with VBA for every quarter of years from 2001 to 2012 with following code:

```
For Y = 2001 To 2012
    For M = 1 To 4 Step

    s = Str(Y) & "_" & Str(M)
    Sheets.Add.Name = s

   Next M
Next Y
```

So there are sheets in my workbook that look like: 2012_4, 2012_3, 2012_2, ... , 2001_2, 2001_1 (they are in that order).

In all of my procedures I am addressing to these sheets by their names. But is there some other way using their order? Is there "first" and "last" sheets?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes: What exactly have you tried? If no: Why should anyone consider helping if you do not even show effort? - Many good questions contain code, but that does not automagically make a question with code a good one. ;)

Comment: I tried searching two books I have on VBA. And googling several times. I didn't understand what I want to understand. Maybe I should have formulated my question differently. I am not asking to write a code for me. I just want somebody to explain me logic behind sheets organization in a workbook and how can I address it using VBA. If it isn't a proper question I will delete it.

Comment: Last two questions were bad, I agree. I just have found answers for them easily. I have edited my question.

Comment: The question is valid, it is just not in a form that makes clear that you tried to solve your problem and how you failed at solving it. - As a first hint: You could start by reading [the VBA language reference on the Workbook-Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224504%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this reference. It is a usefull one. I have found an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub testing()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    ws.Copy after:=Worksheets("Sheet1") ' you can use before:= or after:= a worksheet
    Set newWs = ActiveSheet
    newWs.Name = "Sheet1 Copy" ' renaming any sheet
End Sub

Sub loopingSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```